# Iterate over an object where the condition is less than the increment

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array `CELL = [abc, def, xyz]`

and i have two variables `CONST START_LINE = 45` and `CONST COLUMN = 'D'`

I am trying to get iterate over `CELL` to get a new object as
`To_include = {'abc' : D45, 'def':D61, 'xyz':77}`

I tried the below but not getting the right output

```
Concat_rows_array =[];
To_add = {};
  if (Concat_rows_array.length==0){
    for (var i = 0; i <= CELL.length; i += 16){
      Temp_START_LINE = i + START_LINE;
      To_add[Cell] = COLUMN+Temp_START_LINE;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(To_add);
```

I am new to this, please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If `To_add` is `To_include`, it is required to modify it.
- If your variables are `const CELL = ["abc", "def", "xyz"];`, `const START_LINE = 45;`, `const COLUMN = 'D';`, `To_add[Cell]` is required to be modified like `To_include[CELL[i]]`.
- In the case of `for (var i = 0; i <= CELL.length; i += 16){,,,}`, it is required to be `i < CELL.length`.
- If you want to retrieve `To_include = {'abc' : D45, 'def':D61, 'xyz':77}`, it is required to check the last element in the loop.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const CELL = ["abc", "def", "xyz"];
const START_LINE = 45;
const COLUMN = 'D';

Concat_rows_array = [];
To_include = {};
if (Concat_rows_array.length == 0) {
  const len = CELL.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Temp_START_LINE = START_LINE + (16 * i);
    To_include[CELL[i]] = (i < len - 1 ? COLUMN : "") + Temp_START_LINE;
  }
}
console.log(To_include);
```

- When this scrpt is run, `To_include` is `{"abc":"D45","def":"D61","xyz":"77"}`.

Comment: You are a savior and pure genius @Tanaike -san. thank you so much

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.